# Number of ways to form committee of 5 people

Tags: probability, combinations

I am trying to solve the following problem on combinations:

> You wish to select five persons from seven men and six women to form a
> committee that includes at least three men.
>
> a. In how many ways can
> you form the committee?
>
> b. If you randomly choose five persons to form
> the committee, what is the probability that you will get a committee
> with at least three men?

My attempt:

a) Number of ways = $ C(7,3) * C(10,2) = 1575 $ 
b) Sample space = $ C(13,5) = 1287 $

Now the working for (b) looks pretty strange because the probability will be $ \frac{1575}{1287}  > 1 $ which is definitely incorrect. Can anyone please advise me what is wrong here?

Comment: Isn't it $C(6,2)$ instead of $C(10,2)$ above?

Comment: There are 10 people left. Hence it is $ C(10,2) $

Comment: it's at least 3 men, so you need to consider 3,4 & 5 men on the committe - you have fixed at 3 men and two women in (a) - also in (a) I don't see why it is 2 from 10 as opposed to 2 from six

Comment: There are ten people left, but some of them are men, The rest of the two people you want to choose, you want them to be women, right?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг No, the commitee need *at least* three men, so it can be all-men.

Comment: I see what's gone wrong, you have counted the possibility of some men twice in C(10,2), that you already counted in C(7,3) - you need to add 3 terms together I think

Comment: Oh, I did not read that part. Right.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton Yes, your second comment is correct, the first is not.

Comment: Oh. I understand why the second operation has to choose within 6 candidates now. The men must be counted in the first operation and the women in the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) is incorrect, because you count some selections of men twice. For example, picking the first five men is counted in:

- I first pick the first three men, then the fourth and fifth
- I first pick men 1,2,4, then 3,5
- I first pick 1,2,5, then 3,4

and so on. So, basically, in your solution to (a), you made a distinction between "men chosen as one of the first three" and "men chosen as one of the final two", a distinction that doesn't really exist.

So your answer for (a) is not correct. I suggest just summing the numbers for a commitee with *exactly* three, four or five men.

Comment: +1 clear explanantion. Thanks for all your help! I managed to compute the correct answer.